# Typescript create type that uses other field in a dynamic way

Tags: typescript

There's a couple of questions related to this but none I could find that match my requirements.

I wish to create a factory that, based on the type, requires a factory for each key of that object that contains the value and the entire object. For example:

```
type Row = {
  foo: string
  bar: number
  baz: unknown
}

const factory: MyMagicType<Row> = [{
  field: 'foo',
  // Infers value as string
  factory: (value, obj) => ..
}, {
  field: 'bar',
  // Infers value as number
  factory: (value, obj) => ..
}]
^also throws that 'baz' hasn't been populated
```

I have tried using generics for this but got stuck.

```
type MyMagicType<TObj extends Record<string, unknown>, TField extends keyof TObj> {
  field: TField,
  factory: (val: TObj[TField], source: TObj) => any
}[]
```

But this doesn't work due to the field needing to be inferred rather than passed into the generic.

How can I omit the `TField` but still let it infer from `field`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure how you want to type the second parameter and the return value of your factory functions, but here is a possible implementation of `MyMagicType` that types the first parameter correctly:

```
type Row = {
  foo: string
  bar: number
  baz: unknown
};

type MyMagicType<T extends object> = Array<{
  [K in keyof T]: {
    field: K,
    factory: (value: T[K], obj: any) => any,
  }
}[keyof T]>;

const factory: MyMagicType<Row> = [{
  field: 'foo',
  // Infers value as string
  factory: (value, obj) => undefined
}, {
  field: 'bar',
  // Infers value as number
  factory: (value, obj) => undefined
}];
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBASg9gdygXigbwFBSgMznALigGdgAnASwDsBzLKAIwEMyiqBXAWwYjPuYBeRdlQDWVRFQwBfANwYMoSFACyIFUxoUAxgBVwEADy6oEAB7AIVACbEocBgCsI24AD4UUAIJkyTEIaY2ADaANJQ1FCiECBwOFC6ALpEQdi4FBAANtZEoQA09Ng4TK5wZCBEABQAbkyZ7BBEumGJefZORExUIACUKB5dIAXY0jLB0bHxSW7yGNpwVKS4JcBlFarqmjr6kIbwCB6owak4GdlEAOR4cBfDUAD091AAklQ4vHa19dBMdqSUtHoxVK5SqXwabQcjj6yA8ImsEFOVAg1hkbROZxyUAuzDIt3ojxebw%20UHBPzsHG4vCBKzWYLqEPa0P6UHhiOoKJkiVkQA)

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much. That's really clever, I had the `[K in keyof T]` but didn't have the second part with the accessor to infer the key. Thanks for saving me an afternoon of trial and error.